# Как правильно выводить html разметку через PHP?

Tags: вывод, php

Привет всем!

Уже давно мучает вопрос, на который нигде нет внятного ответа, поэтому решил все-таки спросить здесь.

Объясню суть вопроса.

1) Допустим, нам нужно распечатать страницу html. На этой странице у нас содержатся какие-нибудь данные из базы данных. Одно время я печатал так:

`private function PrintSomething()
{
    echo '<div class="test1" onclick="test.testTest(1, \'22\')">';
        echo '<div style="color: #eee;">';
            echo $this->test;
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}`

Тем самым сохраняется читабельный вид документа, ведь построен он как дерево.
Но есть одно но, если у меня будет очень большая страница, то количество функций echo достигает такого количества, что я начинаю сомневаться в правильности выбранного варианта вывода.

2) Естественно, после этого, я решил объединить все функции echo в одну echo, но тут возникает другая проблема: если посмотреть в браузере этот текст, то все переносы, табуляции сохраняются. Конечно, на отображаемой браузером странице ничего не видно из этого, но если какой-нибудь человек откроет код HTML этой страницы в своем браузере, то он ужаснется.

3) Использование Heredoc style и двойных кавычек приводит к такой же проблеме, как во втором пункте.

4) Были и другие варианты. Пробовал выводить html разметку вне php кода, закрывая перед текстом тег php. Но как и во втором варианте такая же проблема.

Можно, конечно, писать весь html код не сохраняя структуру дерева, но в конце концов получится кодовое месиво, в которой ничего в дальнейшем не поймешь.
Приходит в голову мысль, что все табуляции сохраняет IDE, но не найду как это исправить.

Всегда строил страницу по первому способу, но потом задумался о скорости данного метода.

Если кто-то тут сталкивался с данной проблемой, просьба, напишите как вы решили свою проблему. Использую PhpStorm 7.

Answer (score 5):

Откройте для себя шаблоны. Начать можно с этих статей:

- [Шаблоны в PHP. Часть I.](http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/shablony_v_php.html) Тут же рассматривается решение подобное вашему.
- [Шаблоны в PHP. Часть II.](http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/shablony_v_php_chast_2.html)
- [PHP FAQ. Шаблоны](http://phpfaq.ru/tpl)

Слепо всем советам можете не следовать, но ознакомиться стоит.

Comment: Спасибо, это решает мою проблему.

Comment: Ну хоть наконец то кто то написал что PHP и есть самый мощный и крутой шаблонизатор и всякие там смарти.tpl это костыли

Answer (score 0):

MVC!!!!!!!

Познакомся с решением этой задачи в современных фреймворках. В свое время реализация MVC в Kohana перевернула мое представление о back-end разработке.